# How to Handle Safe Area Space in SwiftUI While Ignoring It

Tags: swiftui, safearealayoutguide

I want to completely color the background of my app while at the same time positioning content at the top so that its far enough from the status bar and top notch on those devices that have it.

If I do something like this:

```
@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Text("Top of my view")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

This displays the text at the top of the content, below the safe area. But only the content area is yellow. The safe areas are white.

So I add `.edgesIgnoringSafeAreas(.all)` below the `.background` modifier.

Now my text is below the notch (or smack up at the top of the screen below the Status bar text) and not visible.

I don't want to randomly guess at a top padding because that might be fine on phones with notches but look wrong on phones or iPads without notices.

If I place my `VStack` inside of a `GeometryReader`, the `reader.safeAreaInsets.top` is zero (0) when the top safe area is ignored.

I hope this a clear enough question. Has anyone run into this and have a solution?

Comment: @vacawama `background` will be limited to the `VStack` width, so `frame` might be needed in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` modifier to `Color.yellow` only.

A possible solution is to use a `ZStack`:

```
@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Text("Top of my view")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. Never occurred to me to do it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix it is to apply `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` just to the `Color.yellow` inside of `.background()`:

```
@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Text("Top of my view")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, too. Never thought to do it this way, either.